# Pickerboxdialog Customizing

Tags: windows-phone-7

So, I'm attempting to use this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/17/customizing-picker-box-dialog.aspx

However, I just want a normal pickerboxdialog (just text) but I'd like to attach an id to it, so I can easily reference the selection the user picked. However, even after building my own class to pass in, I still cannot get the text to display properly (IE at all) within the pickerbox.

Does anyone have an experience? I basically copied his code and still no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a normal picker box then you shouldn't have to worry about customizing the template (unless you want to display the ID too).

The way you reference the object selected by the user is just in the Closed event handler:

```
void Dialog_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var picker = (PickerBoxDialog)sender;
     var selected = (YourCustomObject)picker.SelectedItem;
}
```

In other words you shouldn't need the ID of the selected object because you can get a reference select object directly.

Answer (score 1):

The [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) includes a `ListPicker` control which provides the functionality you're after.

It displays like the so called "picker box" but also includes a `SelectedItem` property and a `SelectionChanged` event.